# PCIe with multiple devices in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When using **PCIe** with multiple devices on it (for example: serial, canbus, i2c, etc.):

1. Is it that there is a **single kernel pci driver** which handles all these devices ?
2. Or should it be implemented by using **multiple pci device drivers**, each using the same DEVICE_ID and VENDOR_ID ?

**If we use the first method:**

Does it mean we need **not** call "`request_region`" becuase the same resource are used in different drivers ?

**If we use the second method above:**

What about the **interrupt** routine ? Is it a single interrupt routine for all these devices ?

Can anyone reference an example from kernel source tree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on one of your other questions, I am assuming you are talking about FPGA with custom IP blocks connected over PCIe to a ARM CPU complex.

1. PCIe driver does not handle any of these devices. The memory map/space for these IP blocks would be exposed over PCIe. When any of these peripheral devices trigger an IRQ, the IRQ would become a PCIe MSI IRQ and given to the respective peripheral driver's IRQ handler.
2. There will not be multiple PCIe device drivers.

See my response to one of your another queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055736/how-existing-kernel-driver-should-be-initialized-as-pci-memory-mapped/54069081#54069081).

Comment: 2. Why not? If PCIe device is representing several functions it would be several drivers. Otherwise it would same set of drivers + one MFD kind of.